# nodejs napi How to manually create a CallbackInfo type data

Tags: node.js, node-addon-api

I want to call some existing functions, but the function requires the CallbackInfo parameter, how do I initialize a CallbackInfo

```cpp
Value b(const CallbackInfo& info)
{
  ...
}

Value a(const CallbackInfo& info)
{
  CallbackInfo newInfo = CallbackInfo::New();
  return b(newInfo);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more info? Like module what are you trying to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
void b(const CallbackInfo& info)
{
  printf("function b\n");
}

void a(const CallbackInfo& info)
{
   auto js_this = info.This().As<Napi::Object>();

  if (js_this.Has("b") && js_this.Get("b").IsFunction())
  {
    js_this.Get("b").As<Napi::Function>().Call(info.This(), {});
  }
}
```